# Question about Reduction Map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

My question refers to following step in the construction of the reduction map in section 10.1.3 (Liu's Algebraic Geometry; page 467):

[image]

If we consider a point $x \in X$ of the generic fiber $X = f^{-1}(\eta)$ where $f: \chi \to S$ is the surj proper morphism into Dedekind scheme $S$ and $\eta$ the generic point of $S$. 
That's alredy clear that if we consider the special case $S= \mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ so $S$ is Sierpinski space with unique generic point $\eta$ and closed point $\sigma$, then for every $x \in X$ the intersection $\overline{\{x\}} \cap \chi_s$ isn't empty (easy argument by contradiction).

The thing which isn't clear to me is why $\overline{\{x\}} \cap \chi_s$ is only one point.

I suppose that the Henselian property of $S$ provides the answer but don't see how...

Comment: The intersection you are considering is a closed subscheme of $\overline{\{x\}}$, and therefore finite over $S$. Moreover, it is supported over $s$. Thus, it is finite over Spec $k(s)$, and thus a finite union of  closed points in $\mathcal{X}_s$. So, to conclude, it suffices to show that the intersection you are considering is irreducible.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar: Hi. Thank you for the answer. Two things staying unclear for me. Firstly: What does that mean that the intersection is "finite over S"? Do you mean of finite type (so affine subsets locally are quotients of polynomial rings over $S$)? Secondly: Following your advise I tried to proof that the intersection is irreducible, so consists of one point (because dim zero): by contradiction: Let assump we have at least two points $x_1, x_2$. Can I assump that $x_i= V(f_i)$ for polynomials $f_i$ with coefficients in $k(s)= S/m_s $? If yes, why?

Comment: My intention is to use Henselian property by considering the union $x_1 \cup x_2 = V(f_1 f_2)$ and then lift the product $f_1 f_2$ to polynomials over $S$...

Comment: Finite over Spec $k(s)$ means affine and proper (or quasi-finite and proper, or "locally" a finite $O_S$-module). Anyway, as it is finite over Spec $k(s)$ it is of the form Spec $A$ with $A$ a finitely generated $k(s)$-module.